# VIDEO HLS (m3u8) - Simulate a local connection rate?

Tags: ffmpeg, localhost, video-streaming, video.js, http-live-streaming

I am in local development, wampserver and laravel 5.3

I use ffmpeg to convert video files to HLS (video.m3u8).

The quality adapts according to the user's connection speed. Youtube uses this technology.

I now want to test according to the bitrate but I am in local. 
The video plays automatically in the best format.

Is there a solution to simulate a local connection rate?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're sending data over HTTP, check out Fiddler.  https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler  It has the ability to simulate slower speeds.

An alternative is to use a tool like Clumsy which can simulate poor network conditions at the network level.  https://jagt.github.io/clumsy/  I've had trouble with it under Windows 10, but it seems fine under Windows 7.

There are commercial traffic shaper applications as well.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use Chrome for HLS testing and throttling, this keeps my testing needs all one place/one application. In Chrome install the "Native HLS PLayback" plugin, this allows you to enter a m3u8 URL right into Chrome and play it back. Then open up Chrome's Developer Tools, go to the Network tab, and then go to 'Networks conditions' - in here you can do Network throttling and specify whatever download/upload speeds you want. This should allow to test/view your different bitrates.